# The Hilbert space that contains the first order correction to the state vector in Time-independent Perturbation Theory

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, hilbert-space, perturbation-theory

When deriving the expression for the first order correction to the state vector of the new hamiltonian ( $H = H^0 + H^\prime$ )

we assume that

$$|\psi_n^1\rangle = \sum_{m ~\neq~ n} C_m^{(n)}|\psi ^0 _m\rangle\tag 1$$

(The justification in a popular book being, "the set of $|\psi_n^0\rangle$ forms a complete set.)

This means that the Hilbert space of the new Hamiltonian can be specified by the same basis as that of the Hilbert space assosciated with the unperturbed Hamiltonian. **How can we assume this**?

Or is the Hilbert space of the state vector for a problem specified by the boundary conditions alone?

On a side note the $m=n$ term in equation 1 can be shown to be redundant using equation $(2)$. Therefore the $m = n$ term can be added to equation $(1)$ to remove $m\neq n$ sign. So that the sum happens over all $m$ including $m=n.$ This is just to state that the assumption (equation 1 ) involves assuming the eigen basis of the new Hilbert space to be the same as that in the case of the unperturbed Hamiltonian. 
$$(H^0 - E_n^0) |\psi_n^0\rangle  = - (H^\prime-E_n^1)  |\psi_n^0\rangle \tag 2$$

Comment: This question makes little sense: the Hilbert space is fixed a priori. Put in other words, how you could define the Hamiltonian without  defining on which space it acts on?

Comment: Given a Quantum mechanical system,you know what the Hamiltonian of the system is .But What we don't know is the list of possible states of the system or the basis of the Hilbert space that contains them. The question is trying to explore what determines the uniqueness of the Hilbert space?what information does one need to determine this Hilbert space,is it just the Hamiltonian or the boundary conditions or both? Approach the question along these lines and determine if the Hilbert space of the states  is changed when a perturbation is introduced.

Comment: What is the Hamiltonian for you? As far as I know, it is usually defined as some *self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space* . You can't define an operator on a Hilbert space, if you do not know the Hilbert space itself. So when you say "we know the Hamiltonian but not the possible states", it does not make much sense.

Comment: Consider a quantum harmonic oscillator ,i know that the Hamiltonian operator for the system is given by  H = P^2 /(2*m)  + 0.5*k*x^2                                                I do not know the states of the system,but it can be determined  by solving the Schrodinger equation for the above Hamiltonian . Therefore, in this problem i do not know the Hilbert space associated with the system a priori ,however the the basis can be determined by solving the Schrodinger equation.

Comment: But this is because of your lack of knowledge, not because of the theory! :-P The Hilbert space for that theory is $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (for a $d$-dimensional particle); and it is the same for any perturbation. Of course if you change the Hamiltonian the solutions of the Schrödinger equation change, but always in the same space. Only in much more complicated situations (i.e. with renormalization in QFT) a change of Hilbert space due to the "perturbation", i.e. interaction, is necessary (but that is a whole different story).